# How to prove $|A+B|^2=|A|^2+2 \operatorname{Re}(A \bar{B})+|B|^2$?

Tags: complex-analysis

From my teacher , I know that $|A+B|^2=|A|^2+2 \operatorname{Re}(A \bar{B})+|B|^2$.
So far I know from where $|A|^2$ and $|B|^2$ appear from $|A+B|^2= A \bar{A}+A \bar{B}+\bar{A} B+ B \bar{B},$ but  I can’t see why there is a $2\operatorname{Re}$ in the middle.

Comment: If you know the geometric interpretation of complex addition and multiplication, this is essentially the law of cosines.

Comment: Your  use of \mathrm{} instead of \operatorname{} is the reason why you didn't have proper spacing between $2$ and $\operatorname{Re},$ thus you saw $2\mathrm{Re}$ instead of $2\operatorname{Re}.$ With \operatorname{}, the spaces to the left and right depend on the context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\overline{A\overline B}=\overline{A}\cdot\overline{\overline B}=\overline A B$.

Let $z=A \overline B.$  Say $z=x+yi$ with $x,y\in\mathbb R$.

Then $(x+yi)+(x-yi)=2x,$ so $z+\overline z=2\operatorname{Re}(z)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\renewcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}$

$\renewcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}$

So you just need to varify that $2\Re(A\overline B) = A\overline B + \overline A B$.

Well note  $(w + ui)(x - yi) = (wx +uy) +(ux - wy)i$.

But $(w-ui)(x+yi) = (wx + uy) + (-ux +wy)i = (wx + uy) -(ux-wy)i$.

So..... J.W. Tanners answer.... $2\Re(A\overline B) = A\overline B + \overline A B$.

But alternatively see my exhaustive answer below.

=====

First:

$A\overline B = (\Re A + i\Im A)(\Re B - i\Im B) = $

$[\Re A\Re B + \Im A\Im B] + [\Im A\Re B - \Re A\Im B]i$

So $\Re(A\overline B) = \Re ARe B + \Im A\Im B$.

And then ..... we just do it.

$A+B = [\Re A+ \Re B] + [\Im A + \Im B]i$.

$|A+B| = \sqrt{[\Re A+ \Re B]^2 + [\Im A + \Im B]^2} $

$|A+B|^2 =  [\Re A+ \Re B]^2 + [\Im A + \Im B]^2 = $

$\Re A^2 + 2\Re A\Re B + \Re  B^2 + \Im A^2 + \Im B^2 + 2\Im A\Im B=$

$(\Re A^2 + \Im A^2) + 2(\Re A \Re B + \Im A\Im B) + (\Re B^2 + \Im B^2)=$

$|A|^2 + 2(\Re A\overline B) + |B|^2$

Comment: Try using `\renewcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}` and then using `\Re` from that point on. Things will look a lot better

Comment: Neat hint.  I *hate* typing \\operatorname{foo} a gazillion times.  I assume this will work for any command.  That's huge help....

Comment: That’s exactly right. If you want it curly, as I see you’ve done, `\Re` By default gives $\Re$

Comment: It does?  So I did \renewcommand{\Re}{\mathscr{Re}} for nothing.  Actually I'm not sure I want curly.  Maybe I'll \operatorname.

Comment: If you want to change it back, just delete `\renewcommand` and you’ll still have all the `\Re` in the body

Comment: Hmm.... on second thought \operatorname looks nice.  I didn't know there was a \Re command at all.  Um... can I make up a command say, \lcm... they have \gcd but not lcm via \newcommand{\lcm}{\operatorname{lcm}?

Comment: You can do literally anything. And it’s nice too because it automatically spaces things, like $666\operatorname{fleablood}420x$ as opposed to $666\mathrm{fleablood}420x$